# Удаление записей из таблицы

Tags: sql-server

Необходима Ваша помощь!
Нужно удалить все записи о продажах в которых цена товаров в интервале 15000 до 35000 в таблице Продажа 
Помогите пожалуйста реализовать данный запрос. 
Мой неудачный вариант:

```
DELETE FROM Продажи
WHERE Код_товара in (Select Цена From Товар)
AND [Код_товара] in (Select [Цена] From Товар)  Товар.Цена BETWEEN 15000 AND 35000
```

[image: Таблицы]

Comment: Запросы не пишут по некоему мистическому наитию. Изобретать собственный синтаксис - бесполезно, сервер его понимать откажется. Изучайте [DELETE (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms189835(v%3dsql.110)), особенно пример "C. Using joins and subqueries to data in one table to delete rows in another table". В Вашем конкретном случае - следует использовать JOIN.

Comment: Все равно ничего не получается, что именно тут можно сделать???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Вам хватит и одгного условия вхождения
2) Чтобы проверять что `[Код_товара] in (Select * From Товар),` нужно иметь в таблице `[Товар]` тот самый код товара, ну и искать соответственно `(Select [Код_товара] From Товар)`

Ну и варианты решения задачи:

```
DELETE FROM Продажи
WHERE [Код_товара] in (SELECT [Код_товара] From Товар WHERE Товар.Цена BETWEEN 15000 AND 35000)
```

плюс, как верно заметил @Akina гораздо эффективнее будет так:

```
DELETE s
FROM Продажи AS s
JOIN Товар AS p ON s.[Код_товара] = p.[Код_товара]
WHERE p.Цена BETWEEN 15000 AND 35000
```

Это то что вы пытались сделать, по крайней мере.

Comment: Если нет, давайте больше вводных, скрипты таблиц и полную задачу.

Comment: `WHERE .. IN` - штука тормозна-а-ая... JOIN будет побыстрее, к тому же он может гораздо эффективнее использовать индексы.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!!